# Решение задачи о рюкзаке методом ветвей и границ

Tags: алгоритм, методы

Каков алгоритм решения вышеупомянутой задачи? 
В википедии написано следующее:

> Оригинальный алгоритм, предложенный Питером Колесар (англ. Peter Kolesar) в 1967 году, предлагает отсортировать предметы по их удельной стоимости (отношению ценности к весу) и строить дерево полного перебора. Его улучшение заключается в том, что в процессе построения дерева, для каждого узла мы оцениваем верхнюю границу ценности решения, и продолжаем строить дерево только для узла с максимальной оценкой[10]. Когда максимальная верхняя граница оказывается в листе дерева, алгоритм заканчивает свою работу.

Что представляет собой дерево полного перебора?

Что такое верхняя граница ценности решения?

Каков в принципе общий алгоритм решения задачи о рюкзаке данным способом? Полезным будет код или псевдокод решения этой задачи

Answer (score 2):

Если по простому, то:

У нас есть узел, это наше текущее состояние, т.е. количество предметов, которое лежит в данный момент в рюкзаке. Также у нас есть ветви, это соединительные пути к другим узлам (состояниям), т.е. как будто мы кладём одну вещь в рюкзак.

Допустим у нас есть пустой рюкзак грузоподьёмностью (5кг) и нам надо положить: ноутбук (2кг), спальник (3кг), молот (5кг).

Тогда дерево полного перебора будет выглядеть следующим образом:

[image: Дерево полного перебора]

В этом дереве мы можем заметить, что у нас есть узлы, которые превышают вес рюкзака и при этом у них есть ещё и потомки, а зачем нам продолжать рассматривать следующие варианты, если дальше будет только хуже? Поэтому мы ограничиваем весом 5 и получаем такой граф:

[image: Отсекаем по границе заведомо ложные решения]

На выходе получаем, что есть 2 варианта, либо мы кладём в рюкзак: ноутбук и спальник, либо молот.

В зависимости от реализации, можно искать все варианты, первый или задать дополнительные критерии оптимальности.

Comment: то есть метод ветвей и границ предполагает исключение как раз тех узлов, которые превышают вес рюкзака?

Comment: В данном, конкретном случае, да

Comment: а что будет ценностью решения для каждого узла в данном случае? в тому же, в задаче о рюкзаке присутствует еще и цена, как все это связать?

Comment: В качестве цены тут выступает вес, а ценности решения его сумма, вы можете задать по другому.